Do I point Unicode Triangles Up/Down when Open/Closed?
I have a <div> with an <h1> and a hidden <p> underneath the <h1>.
Clicking on the <h1> "slideToggles" the <p>.
Question:
When the <p> is hidden; does the <h1> show an ▼ or an ▲? Which one tells the user that a menu will slide down?
Snippet:


$('div h1').click(function() {

        $(this).next('p').toggleClass('open');

        var $h1 = $('div').find('h1');

        $h1.text($h1.text().includes('▼') ? $h1.text().replace('▼', '▲') : $h1.text().replace('▲', '▼'));

    });
div, h1, p {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    border:1px solid silver;
}
h1 {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid silver;
    cursor: pointer
}
h1:hover {
    color: silver;
}
p {
    padding: 0 10px;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 300ms ease;
}
.open {
    max-height: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1>Header ▼</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



Update
According to the comments it's ▼ when closed and ▲ when open.

I thought it was sideways when closed and down when open.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk not always, its usually the case in submenus..

There's no standard for this.

Its ▲ when opened and ▼ when closed since ▼ depicts that the menu can be opened and ▲ depicts that the menu can be closed.
See this for example :-
Closed:

Opened:


This seems opinion-based. Do you have some authoritative reference?

@Ouroborus it is a custom approved by the community since it is one of the easiest indicators, see this for instance: https://blog.stackfindover.com/css-accordion-menu-examples/.

You can also see this in the header menu of the stackoverflow.co as well

In what scenario does it make sense to have an upwards pointing triangle when content appears below? Perhaps it's not as opinion-based as it seems at first.

@Jordy you've got the wrong idea, the upward triangle does not signify the Y-position of the menu, rather it's where the menu goes on closing it..

I agree, that's what I meant; it does not make sense having the arrow pointing up. When the menu is closed, and after a click, appearing below.

Those aren't authoritative. Those are just examples you happened to find. There's nothing there attempting to set a standard. Conversely, this page claims to document best practices and, even then, uses + and × for the example icons. It also only goes so far as to say that accordions have two icons but avoids saying what those icons should be.

If you just need a counter example, Confluence uses down- and right-pointing arrows for its accordions and other collapsible areas. See Expand Macro.
